# Import functions into Background.js file Chrome Extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, create-react-app, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, npm-build

I'm creating a Chrome extension with React using CRA.

I want to use some helper functions within the `/src` folder inside of the `background.js` file, which causes the error `Cannot use import statement outside a module` because it's in the public folder.

The `background.js` file has to be in the same folder as the `manifest.json` file for `version 3` of the manifest.json`.

Any suggestions on how to move `manifest.json` and `background.js` into the `/src` folder and still have it build properly with `npm run build`, which currently uses `react-scripts build`?

Current Folder Structure:
[image]

Comment: The background script can be anywhere since Chrome 93 so why don't you restrict your extension from being installed in earlier versions of the browser by specifying minimum_chrome_version?

Comment: @wOxxOm that sounds like a good suggestion. I'm getting errors when trying to load unpacked - `Could not load background script 'src/background.js'. Could not load manifest.`

My manifest.json is loading the script `"service_worker": "src/background.js"`

Comment: You need to specify the final path of the file when it's in the `build` directory, not in the source.

Comment: @wOxxOm When react builds it just builds the public folder and then takes everything else and creates chunk js files. So there isn't a final path to that exact file

Comment: Since the error message mentions `src/` it means this string is copied verbatim, consequently it is up to you to specify the correct path there. The correct path won't be in `src`, it will be relative to `build`. If background.js is copied into `build` then there's no additional path. If it's copied into a subfolder there then you need to use that name. If the name gets a hash id then you need to disable this feature.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the suggestions. Ended up doing a work around of just doing native fetch operations and using chrome storage api inside of `background.js` so I didn't have to import anything. Kept the file inside of the public folder.